# Fast way to build special datetime range in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have two lists. One is list of datetime assume: d (10000 elements), one is list of int assume: m (1000 elements).

I would like to generate a new list of datetime, which is the shift of m minutes of d.

To put it more intuitively, I am trying to do following code:

```py
[x + datetime.timedelta(minutes = y) for x in d for y in m]
```

The trouble is the speed is very slow for above double loops. Is there any faster way to handle it? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried resample in the date into minute intervals

Comment: Isn't [pandas.date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) what you are looking for?

Comment: will you demonstrate what the output should look like.  so the final time will be x+1000 minutes?

Comment: @Chris zip will stop after the shorter sequence is exhausted - wouldn't make sense to me either ;-) OP should provide [mre].

Comment: If you want it fast, the Numpy library should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce time, just reuse `datetime.timedelta(minutes=y)`. For example, trade a little space with the run time.

```
M = [ datetime.timedelta(minutes=y) for y in range(1000)]  # trade space
[x + y for x in d for y in M] # save time
```

Example:

```
import datetime,time

d = [ datetime.date(2022, 10, _%30+1 ) for _ in range(10000)]
m = [ _ for _ in range(1000) ] 
M = [ datetime.timedelta(minutes = y ) for y in range(1000)] 

start_time = time.time()
[x + datetime.timedelta(minutes = y) for x in d for y in m]
print("from time: {}".format(time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
result = [x + y for x in d for y in M]
print("to time: {}".format(time.time()-start_time))
```

The Output:

```
from time: 7.302632093429565
to time: 0.6205151081085205
```

Comment: How can you claim the complexity is decreasing when you're looping through the same number of elements?

Comment: It's more like moving from bubble sort to selection sort, same big-O but actually fewer number of operations.

Comment: And thanks @Mark Ransom and FObersteiner 's reminder. I forget to specify what time complexity in terms of.  The above time complexity is not with respect to whole chunk of code, but in terms of number of executions of datetime.timedelta.   So, I just updated the answer, to make it clear.

Comment: I think there's still a slight error, it should be O(m) not O(d).

Comment: P.S. `time.time()` isn't the recommended way to do code timing, `timeit` is.

Comment: if d is constant O(dm) becomes O(m) automatically. That's very basic. Bro.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, yes, `timeit` is another very good tool to measure the runtime, especially for small pieces of code. And there are actually many different ways to time for different aspects. As for this demo's purpose, `time.time()` should already be sufficient.  ... And nevertheless, if anyone wants to publish a paper on this, I would choose timeit for more subtle experiments for anyone who would held suspicious of results.

Comment: If your algorithm's execution time depends on the sizes of two inputs multiplied, it's O(N*M) technically. So neither d nor m are constants you can drop here I think. But no, I'm not going to write the paper ;-)

Comment: lol. It is also a much better experience than replying editor's blind review.  BTW, yes, you are correct, it is just that you are talking about the overall time complexity. It is not the same thing I wrote. Please be aware, time complexity does not always (even though by default) bundle with the "overall operators".  We can, and should, specify "with respect to what criterion" whenever the default is not the case.

Comment: Perhaps instead of invoking big-O notation, you should just be explicit about what you mean: old way, n*m calls to `timedelta`, new way only m calls to `timedelta`.